# Sum of residue of two function

Tags: complex-analysis, zeta-functions

Consider $P(s)$ to be the prime zeta function given by

$P(s)=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^{s}}=\sum_{n>0}\frac{\mu(n)Log\zeta(ns)}{n}$

Where $p$ is prime and $\mu$ is the mobius function which is equal to zero if $n$ has square factor .
Now let consider the function $g(s)$ define by 
$g(s)=\zeta(s)-P(s)$ for $Re(s)>0$

We know that zeta have pole at $s=1$ but $P(s)$ have poles when $\zeta(ns)=0 $ or when $ns=1$

Now we have many cases  and also when we comppute the residue at $s=1$ 
We find that $P(1)$ diverge to infinty !

My question is how we can determine the poles of $g(s)$ since it is the sum of two function? and how we can compute the residues of sum of two function have different poles?
 how we can write $g(s)$ as Euler product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\log \zeta(s)$ thus $P(s)$ have a logarithmic singularity at $s=1$ not a pole, such a singularity doesn't have a residue

It works exactly the same at $\rho/n$ for $\rho$ a zero of $\zeta(s)$.

Try with $h_1(s)=1/(s-1)$ and $h_2(s)=\log (s-1)$ to see how $\int_{|s-1|=1/4} h_k(s)ds$ works.

If $h$ is meromorphic at $s=1$ and analytic on $0<|s-1|\le b$ then for all $0<a \le b$ $$\int_{|s-1|=a} g_k(s)ds=2i\pi Res(h(s),1)$$

Comment: I don't understand . so you mean that the only pole is 1 .can you clarify the answer

Comment: $P(s)$ has logarithmic singularities, no poles, such a function doesn't have a residue at its singularities.

Comment: So if I  want to calculate the integral of $P(s)$ in closed counter in which it contains the logarithmic singularities .what I should do

Comment: For some $a_j,c_j$ (can you find them ?) $P(s)-\sum_j c_j\log(s-a_j)$ is analytic on the region so its contour integral vanishes and its reduces to the primitive of $\log(s-a_j)$. But this is not a "closed contour" : see how it works with $\log(s-1)$, how there is a problem of branch, which means we have to continue the function analytically on the contour.

Comment: what about the Euler product can you write $g(s)$ as Euler product

Comment: No. Up to a certain level everything we can do with $\zeta(s)$ is in the books.